# jQuery TokenInput - tokens exceed textbox width

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-tokeninput

I'm having a problem using the jQuery plugin TokenInput. In the demos, when new tokens are added and are too big for the current textbox line, they nicely move to the next line. I am having a problem where they will instead go *past* the textbox border once, *then* move to the next line. So you will only see part of the token, then the textbox cuts it off.

I'm at a complete loss for why this isn't working. I'm using IE8 (it's a requirement). Here's the code I'm using that can reproduce this issue (the files are the same as in the demo, I just had to rename them for testing).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/token-input-facebooktesting.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery.tokeninputtesting.js" defer="defer"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#test").tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php", {
                theme: "facebook"
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div><p>
        <input id="test" type="text"/></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: To update...If I directly copy a working version's HTML, make a new HTML page in visual studio and paste it in there, it will not work. Even though it is the exact same html. What could cause that?

Comment: When you say the files are the same as in the Demo, did you get them from the demo page, or are you using the downloaded ones from github? The Demo currently runs on a slightly older version (1.6.0), compared to 1.6.1 which is available for download. In this version, the resize_input method has been updated, which could be causing your problems with IE8? Perhaps try using 1.6.0 from the demo page source, and see if that solves your problem.